# Python IDLE won't run on Debian/Ubuntu Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.7

I used: "sudo apt-get install idle3" and "sudo apt install idle" in my attempts to install Python IDLE from the terminal. Both worked fine, with a successful installation message afterwards. However, when I type $ idle or $ idle3, nothing happens. When I tried to open it from the "Applications" menu, it also would not open. (Note: I can set up a python file and run it without trouble, so I am sure that both Python2 and 3 are properly installed.) Any suggestions on how to make IDLE run correctly, or maybe to reinstall it a different way so that it actually opens?

Comment: *Nothing happens* is weird. Do you mean that you have no error message and get the prompt immediately? BTW, do `python -m idlelib` or `python3 -m idlelib` still have the same inexistent effect?

Comment: Yes, but I do see an error message: ImportError: cannot import name '_setup_dialog' from tkinter.simpledialog' (/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/simpledialog.py)

Comment: However, I have no idea what this means, as I just installed the OS and have never used Linux previously.

Comment: This looks like a bad Python installation with more than one Python 3 installed version. The error messages says that tkinter is for Python 3.9, while you tagged your question with 3.7...